# Preload images with a blurred preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, image

I have two versions of a picture: A full resolution picture (big resolution, good quality) and a preview picture (small resolution, poor quality Q10, high compressions, very small ~1kb).

To preload images, I try to achieve something facebook did in their post here https://code.facebook.com/posts/991252547593574/the-technology-behind-preview-photos/: Put a small image version inside your image container and scale it up and apply a CSS blur. This acts as a preview, where the user gets a rough impression of the image. Then, load the original picture through JS and swap the images when it's done loading.

Here is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SVUMGCmtTrHJnZXnBVXu?p=preview

```
<style>
  .container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    
  }
  .myImage {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .preview {
    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="myImage preview" 
    data-image-url="http://oi67.tinypic.com/2jfhwck.jpg" 
    style="background-image: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/2jfhwck_th.jpg);">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function imgComplete(img) {
    return img.complete || img.width + img.height > 0;
  }

  function removePreview(container, url) {
    container.css({'background-image': 'url("' + url + '")'});
    container.removeClass('preview');
  }

  $('.preview').each(function(idx, container) {
    container = $(container);
    var url = container.data('image-url');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;

    // if we have this image already cached, we don't have
    // to wait for the onload callback and can remove the
    // preview image immediately
    if(imgComplete(img)) {
      removePreview(container, url);
    } else {
      img.onload = function() {
        removePreview(container, url);
      };
    }
  });
</script>
```

> **The problem ist the flickering**: The first time the image is loaded, it shows the blurred preview, and once the big image is loaded, it's swapped. Then, when you reload the page, you already have the big image cached in your browser, *and it shouldn't show the blurred version.* However, you see it for a short time.
>
> **Anybody an idea, how to prevent the flickering of the blurred preview image, and display the big resolution of the image immediately, if it's already in the browsers cache?**

Comment: One thing, you check for `if(imgComplete(img))` but `imgComplete()` returns nothing (undefined). So you are still waiting for `load` event to fire before removing preview image

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated the plnkr & the code (that was too much ruby with implicit returns I guess). This reduces the flickering in about half the cases, but when you refresh the browser it still happens.

Comment: @23tux do you still need advice for this?

Comment: @Axel yes, this would be great. We skipped the feature so far because of this, so if you have any ideas, let me know!

Comment: @23tux I definitely will as soon as I have a bit time!